# How to apply polymorphism in this object

Tags: java, types, casting, polymorphism, message

I have the following class

```
class Message{
    private List content;
    private String messageType;

    public Message(String messageType, List content){
       this.content = content;
       this.messageType = messageType;
    }
}
```

Okey, now imagine i want to send different message types. For example, the message type "friends". I want to store their ID number (`int` for example) as a key to find their names (`String`). That reminds me that i should use the `HashMap` class.  Or a simple `String`, whatever. And other more cases where i need to use other object types.

The main question here is: how i should proceed here to code a class that have two attributes:

- The first stores the type of the message
- The second is the content itself, which should be able to be any kind of object

I have read that casting is a bad practice, so i dont want to declare `content` as an object and then, cast it in function of the message type.

My thoughts:

- Declare message as an abstract class and then implement subclasses in function of the message type. What i dont get here is that if i declare an abstract method like `getContent()` in `Message` class, i need to stablish the data type that it returns, what get me back to the main issue. This way get useless since i need to send the `Message` and not the subclass.

Comment: When it comes to "polymorphism", it means nothing if your class bears no behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `messageType` at all, you can just define a generic type with class and use it in `content`, e.g.:

```
class Message<T> {
    private List<T> content;

    public Message(List<T> content){
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say if the type is `String`, you can do:

```
Message<String> message = new Message<>(new ArrayList<String>());
```

This way, you can instantiate `Message` class with different types. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) is the documentation on generic class types.

Comment: Now i want to ask you this, what if the `messageType` helps the program to know how to treat with it, for example, if i send a message which type is "search", then takes the content (which have a keyword as a `String`) and makes a search in google with it, does `messageType` make sense?

Comment: @JD0001 : It implies a bad design

Comment: Could you share with me sources to do this properly?

Comment: @JD0001 you can set the type `T` as generic type and override the method in different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Message{
        private List content;
        private HashMap<String,Integer> messageType = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        public Message(HashMap messageType, List content){
            this.content = content;
            this.messageType = messageType;
    }
    }
```

Does this code make sense???

Comment: Obviously not, it's just too long the whole class. This is just a fragment of code to try to explain myself. Its a client - server connection where the client sends a message to the server, then the server answer to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interface that contains the common methods that apply to all message types and the have all the messages implement the Sendable interface.

### Interface

```
 interface Sendable {
  public String getContent();
  public MessageType getMessageType();
}
```

### Message Classes

```
public FriendMessage implements Sendable {

    private String title;
    private Map friends;
    private messageType = MessageType.Friends;

    public String getContent(){
     return title+ friends.toString();
     }

    public MessageType getMessageType() {
     return this.messageType;
   }
}
```

### Enum

```
public Enum MessageType {
 Friends, NoFriends, Lonely
}
```

You should also have an Enum that will classify all your message types. This will allow you to determine the message type without having to do `instanceof` or string comparison.